# How to call a JavaScript function from PHP if click and curl?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, php-curl

I have a little project in which I try to fetch data from a domain and put this information in input fields.

The Curl function is good and working. However, the jQuery script if not working or filling the input fields. If I use `$url = "http://domain...";` , all is working on page load but if I use an input field with a button and post form, the fields are empty. The curl  is working and gives the full page back.

How I can load the script with the same button but after load the curl script?

Button:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label for="name">URLinput</label>
    <input type="url" id="inf_endpoint" name="inf_endpoint" value="" />
    <button type="submit" name="mytest">Test This</button>
</form>
```

What I have tried:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['mytest'])){
    $url=$_POST['inf_endpoint'];
    $agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, html_entity_decode($url));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }else{
        echo 'All is good';
        ?>
        <script>
            jQuery.ajax({

              url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/matches/manage'); ?>',
              type: 'GET',
              success: function(res) {


                  var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.right').each(function(){
                     $('#date').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                   var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.team a:first').each(function(){
                     $('#team1').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                   var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.team a:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
                     $('#team2').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                   var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.match_head .left a:first').each(function(){
                     $('#league').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                   var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.score').each(function(){
                     $('#result').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                   var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.team_logo a:first').each(function(){
                     $('#logo1').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                   var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
                     jQuery(data).find('div.oppo2 a:first').each(function(){
                     $('#logo2').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
                   });

                }
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
} 
?>
```

But this is working on Page load. But not with a if statement with click

```
$url="https://thedomain";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, html_entity_decode($url));
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if($result === false){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}else{
    echo 'All is good';
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

and

```
jQuery.ajax({

      url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/matches/manage'); ?>',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {


          var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.right').each(function(){
             $('#date').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

           var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.team a:first').each(function(){
             $('#team1').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

           var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.team a:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
             $('#team2').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

           var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.match_head .left a:first').each(function(){
             $('#league').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

           var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.score').each(function(){
             $('#result').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

           var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.team_logo a:first').each(function(){
             $('#logo1').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

           var data = jQuery.parseHTML(res);  
             jQuery(data).find('div.oppo2 a:first').each(function(){
             $('#logo2').val(jQuery(this).html()); 
           });

        }
    });
```

Without click function > The Page is loading and fill the fields.

Comment: Try adding path of php file to form's action attribute

Comment: Where are you setting `$result` ?

Comment: `.each(function() { $('#date')` accessing an `id`'d element in a loop implies that you have multiple elements with the same id... which isn't valid and may cause problems. Might also be worth putting your Ajax call inside a `jQuery(document).ready()` function - if the DOM hasn't loaded when the JavaScript runs it'll fail.

Comment: The Script is full working. But only on page load with full path url and without click function. But i need the find function after click a button.

Answer (score 0):

cURL is a security risk even when your dealing with your servers but let me try to point out some items. Someone can get between you and your curl, magic can happen.

Your first line I don't think it's doing the proper check

```
  <?php
if(isset($_POST['mytest'])){
```

change to

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
```

or even better to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
```

Secondly, I can't see where $result is being set, change the following

```
if($result === false){
```

to

```
if(empty($data)){
```

I hope that solves missing points